# AWS API Gateway Malformed Lambda Response

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format) states that the json should return containing a body,headers,and a status code all of which I have. However for whatever reason when I test it in API gateway it returns a malformed response.

This is the output of the method below it.

> "{\"body\": 200, \"headers\": {\"Content-type\":
>   \"application/json\"}, \"statusCode\": 200}"

```
def addnumbers(message, context):

    result = message['num1'] + 1
    print(result)
    resp = {
        "statusCode": 200,
         "body":  result,
        "headers": { "Content-type": "application/json"}
    }
    return (json.dumps(resp))
```

I am currently passing in num1=1 and it doesn't give any better error message. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you try to return the response object directly, instead of converting it to a string with `json.dumps`? Simply `return resp`?

Comment: Still the same issue, could it be something else affecting it aside from the code?

Comment: Are you sure it is returning that response and not throwing an error? Are you checking the function's logs in CloudWatch?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/LHZ9FH7r
I was looking at the logs on the side panel to the right in the api gateway.

Comment: Did you see the Python stack trace in that log? `Endpoint response body before transformations: {"stackTrace": [["/var/task/lambda_function.py", 5, "addnumbers", "result = message['num1'] + 1"]], "errorType": "KeyError", "errorMessage": "'num1'"}`

Comment: I think I found the solution. It may not be the optimal / right one.

It was because I was doing a get that it failed.
I changed the operation to "ANY" then do a POST and it works fine.

Comment: @eternal_atom You should add an answer to close out the issue if you've found the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok buckle in for an answer.

Make sure you have proxy integration enabled on whatever resource you want in your API.

Now go to your lambda. Look at how I was previously trying to pass in num1.I was trying to get it from the "Event" or message. This is where I was tripping up. Also note [(you can't do a get with a body)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)
Rather the input to the lambda should be like this.

> {
>     "queryStringParameters": {
>       "input": "Whatever the input is you want the lambda to test"
>     }
>   }

So now that we have our test configured for the lambda we need to code the lambda itself.

I put this code within :

> def lambda_handler(event, context):
>
> ```
> number = "Hello, " + event['queryStringParameters']['input']
> ```

```
out = {}
out['statusCode'] = 200
out['body'] = number

return (out)
```

Now if you test it should be fine.

Go back to the API Gateway
In the "Query Strings" Section put in input=randomname

It should now return with hello, randomname